# Can we use node-gdal package in angular6 project?

Tags: node.js, angular6, gdal

I am new to angular, trying to use gdal native library in angular 6 project, Since angular uses npm and **GDAL** native library is also available in **node.js**. Can we do this using node-gdal package?

I tried to install node-gdal package and it is installed successfully.When I am going to import gdal in **"app.component.ts** file in my project it is detecting the path where gdal package is installed but giving run time error on browser that **"gdal is undefined"**.

I used following code to install gdal using npm command.

```
npm install gdal --save
```

and followed the link for gdal installation and uses:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal

As much I know, gdal is available in most of the server side language like java, Python, C++, etc. But by using **node-gdal** package can we use this on client side also like angular 6?

Comment: node-gdal is only for server side, for client side it is https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal-js

Answer (score 0):

No, `gdal`, `gdal-next` and `gdal-async` are native Node.js addons (V8 extensions that are loaded into Node.js' executable) and cannot be used in the browser. There used to be an Emscripten port of GDAL entirely in JavaScript that was browser compatible, but the project is not maintained anymore.

(Disclaimer, I am the author of `gdal-async` and I used to be one of the main contributors of `gdal-next`)

Comment: Which is this browser-side GDAL implementation? I can find only node.js implementations.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdal-js